# adding `<form>` to button changes its position

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I have two buttons

one is `width: 70;` aligned left, the other is `width: 30;` aligned right.

**problem**:
when adding `<form>` attribute to the *left button* it goes under the other button and aligns *right*

```
<div id="button">
        <button class="upperright"> 
        this is button right
        </button>

    <form target="_blank" action="https://ticks.co.il/">
        <button type="submit" class="upperleft">  
        this is button left
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

what i want is to keep the button aligned left to the other button after adding `<form>` .

my css:

```
.upperright, .upperleft{
      background-color: #A7A774;
      color: white;
      font-family: peninim;
      padding: 3px 30px 3px 35px;
      margin-left: -5px;
      font-size: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
}
  .upperleft{
      width: 70%;
}
  .upperright{
      width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly what you want you can add float right and a height of 100% to your upperright button and this should solve your problem.

```
     .upperright{
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      float: right;
      }
```

Also you are missing a closing tag on your div

Comment: i added float right and it fixed my problem. thank you! Must i include height : 100%?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="float-left" style="float: left;">
        <form target="_blank" action="https://ticks.co.il/">
            <button type="submit" class="upperleft">this is button left</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right" style="float: right;">
        <button class="upperright">this is button right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this, if I understand what you were looking for correctly.
Tried to use float right in the div with button.